# Why is the cathedral in such a mess?

Tags: batman-1989

In the beginning of the Cathedral scene in [*Batman* (1989)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096895/) we see the inside of the cathedral. It's a mess which suggests that it's not being used. Why was it displayed in such a mess?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Restoring century old buildings is expensive. Don't worry, Bruce wayne made a generous donation to help fix the damage from the Batman/Joker fight And then some after the credits rolled.

Comment: Its a metaphor for the rotten heart of the city.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[From the wiki](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Gotham_Cathedral_(Burton_Films)):

> The Gotham Cathedral is a monolithic cathedral that stands more than
>   800 feet from the ground. Once intended to be the spiritual center of
>   the city, **the Cathedral has since fallen into ruin as the city itself
>   has fallen into corruption and decay.**

Comment: I've searched the web before asking but my google-fu has certainly worsened. Nice catch and thanks.